# Why does Spark Dstream's foreachRDD keep processing a few more micro-batches before stopping due to an exception?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I use Dstream's foreachRDD method to process incoming micro-batches from Kafka.

For some reason whenever there's an exception inside foreachRDD, my program doesn't right away stop its execution, it processes one more microbatch before stopping, which is not what I want as I want it to stop right away.

What is the best way to avoid this? I wrapped the insides of foreachRDD in a try-catch clause and do `System.exit(-1)`, this works, but as far as I understand it is bad.

I thought at first that this had to do with the `spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown` property being set to "true". But I set it to false and it still doesn't stop right away.

Why does it take a while for spark to stop in this situation?

What I've found is this: https://github.com/dibbhatt/kafka-spark-consumer/issues/64

This person seems to have encountered the same problem, and it seems like they came to the conclusion that there's a race condition between the driver and the executor, but I don't understand what kind of race condition, also the insides of foreachRDD are executed on the driver and if I wrap it in a try-catch, I am catching the exception right away. So, I don't understand what kind of driver-executor race condition could be there.

Comment: legacy, why bother?

Comment: @thebluephantom legacy what? Well, I am working with legacy code maybe, I have no time to rewrite it.